# How to sign in a guest player in GameKit

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, multiplayer, gamekit

I want users to still be able to play online when they don't feel like logging in using Game Center. This is how I thought it would work using an anonymous / guest player:

```
GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { viewController, error in
    if let viewController {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        
        // Create a guest player if there was an error logging in. The anonymous / guest 
        // user is created when the user taps "cancel" on the login view controller.
        // (This isn't how it is in my game there are buttons and stuff. This is just more 
        //  straightforward for stackoverflow)
        if error != nil {
            GKLocalPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayer(withIdentifier: UUID().uuidString)
        }
                
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 4
        let matchmakerVC = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)!
        matchmakerVC.matchmakerDelegate = self
                
        GKLocalPlayer.local.register(self)
        self.present(matchmakerVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

However, when the guest player is created using `GKLocalPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayer(withIdentifier: UUID().uuidString)`, I get an alert on my phone saying "Multiplayer Unavailable. Player is not signed in." How can I sign in the user as a guest player and allow for online matchmaking?

Comment: Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkplayer/1520559-anonymousguestplayer) is misleading here i think. i believe they mean: once authenticated, you can generate a kind of dummy *other* player to play with. but not that you can skip authentication entirely and anonymously interact with GameCenter. for example if you do this `request.recipients = [GKLocalPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayer(withIdentifier:uuid)]` you can generate a match w/ yourself and a player called "Guest of <your GC login>..."

Comment: @Fault ah thank u so much for that. Just out of curiosity what do u mean by generate a match with yourself? Won’t both accounts be referring to one device? How would that work

Comment: yes i think that's the idea -- so 2+ people can play on one device. i haven't fully implemented this, but it does appear that the callbacks for both players get posted back to the same device. (meaning you'd have to filter them accordingly.)